# htaccess RewriteRule rewrite to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the url 'test' to a subdirectory in /public. This is a Laravel App end I want to run the content in public/test independend of Laravel so I should be prevented to go through the Laravel router.

/test/whatever should be **invisbly** forwarded to /public/test/whatever (The url should stay /test/whatever).

**I now have this:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test/ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/test/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So far this is forwarding to: /public/test/test/(index.php)

I think I am close...

**Update:**

In the public directory is also a .htaccess file (Original, from Laravel 5.4):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is your htaccess located in /test folder?

Comment: No, in the root.

Comment: Do you have another .htaccess file in the `public` folder?

Comment: the original laravel one. I will add them in my question

Answer (score 1):

You only need the last rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

for the root dir .htaccess file. This will rewrite everything to the `public/.htaccess`, including requests starting with `/test`.

As long as `public/test/` is a directory, and any requested URLs starting with `/test/` are real files inside `public/test`, this will be sufficient, because the conditions

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

will prevent existing files and directories to be handled by `index.php`.

---

If `test` is not an existing directory, or the requests for `/test/...` are not real files, you need additional rules. Possibly in `/public/.htaccess` or in `/public/test/.htaccess`.

---

The reason for `/test` being rewritten to `/public/test/test` was the combination of

```
# /.htaccess
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/test/$1 [L]
```

where `(.*)` already includes `test`, which becomes `public/test/test`, and then

```
# /public/.htaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

because `public/test/test` is not an existing file or directory (-> `RewriteCond`), and is therefore handled by this rule.

Comment: I follow your logic and I am suspecting something else is causing this problem. It is an existing directory btw. I am going to investigate and let you know the results!